# How to make migration to update table RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am stuck with making migration which will update my table Users. I need to set country_code with 1 everywhere where i have "" or NULL for that column.

Thanks

Comment: Why it has to be rails migration? Can it be just SQL (assume you're using SQL DB) query that updates the table?

Comment: What column type is `country_code` that you'd expect it to hold `null`, `''`, and `1`? Or by `1` do you really mean `'1'`?

Answer (score 4):

```
class UpdateCountryCodeColumnUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute %Q(
      UPDATE users
      SET country_code = 1
      WHERE country_code IS NULL OR country_code = ""
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Using double quotes for a string literal only works in some databases, standard SQL uses single quotes for strings and double quotes for identifiers (such as table and column names).

Answer (score 4):

You probably shouldn't alter the data in a migration and only use it to alter the schema.

A lot of devs use rake db:reset which won't run this migration.

A better solution is to create a rake or thor task as a one off or simply just execute the SQL.

Comment: Why shouldn't you alter data in a migration? And how is `db:reset` relevant? Creating a separate rake or thor task for something that you're just going to throw away seems like it would just clutter up your source tree with stuff that will never be used again. This seems like a perfect job for a migration to me.

Answer (score 4):

**Sergei's** answer is your best bet and will update the data (which would be needed first - and is very important) and it lets the database do the work.  If you also need to set the default for going forward (after the update Sergei proposed) you can make a separate migration (to separate activities) and include the below...

You can also use the rails migration helper method `change_column_default`

```
change_column_default :users, :country_code, from: nil, to: 1
```

If you want to make it reversible just use `change_column`...

```
def up
 change_column :users, :country_code, :string, default: 1
end

def down
 change_column :users, :country_code, :string, default: nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def UpdateCountryCodeForUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Users.where("country_code = '' or country_code = NULL")
      .update_attributes({country_code: 1})
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

On rails 5.2 , I needed to update some text attributes in a column & had to use **update_all** instead of **update_attributes**.

```
class UpdateTableColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    TableName.where("my_column = 'my column old value'")
      .update_all({keywords: 'my column new value'})
  end
end
```